Flutter getx trparams (@ variables substitution) does not work for Hebrew locale
I use GetX latest version (get: ^4.6.6) for internationalization.
Normal text processing works fine.
I have a problem with variable substitution for Hebrew locale (he-IL).
When I select English-US locale it works fine. The @ variables are properly processed.
Please see these screenshots:
[@ he-IL locale problem.
@  en-US locale works fine](https://i.sstatic.net/E5ic8.png)
When I select Hebrew-IL locale the @ variables are not substituted and are displayed on screen unchanged.
I have modified the default app to demonstrate the problem.
Every button click changes the locale so the problem is easily seen.
Translations class has an entry:
"You have answered correctly @correctAnswers out of @questionsPerGame"
If locale is en-US the variables are properly processed. Value of correctAnswers is substituted for @correctAnswers.
When locale is Hebrew (he-IL) variable value is not substituted and on screen I see @correctAnswers, unchanged from what I have in the translations class.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      translations: Languages(),
      // locale: const Locale('en', 'US'),
      locale: const Locale('he', 'IL'),
      title: 'GetX I18N Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'GetX I18N Demo'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  Locale heilLocale = const Locale ("he", "IL");
  Locale enusLocale = const Locale ("en", "US");
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
      if (_counter %2 ==0 ) {
        Get.updateLocale(heilLocale);
      } else {
        Get.updateLocale(enusLocale);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int correctAnswers = 11;
    int questionsPerGame = 22;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text('greeting'.tr),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text('greeting'.tr),
            Text('local is ${Get.locale}'),
            Text("summary_line".trParams({
              "correctAnswers": "$correctAnswers",
              "questionsPerGame": "$questionsPerGame"
            })),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Languages extends Translations {
  @override
  Map<String, Map<String, String>> get keys => {
    'en_US': {
      'greeting': 'Hello, welcome to the counter app !',
      "summary_line":
      "You have answered correctly @correctAnswers out of @questionsPerGame",
    },
    'he_IL': {
      'greeting': 'שלום, ברוך הבא לאפליקציית המונה !',
      "summary_line":
      "ענית נכון על correctAnswers@ מתוך questionsPerGame@ שאלות !",
    }
  };
}


